# Need help about Regular Expression Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net

I tried to take only this part(after the "j&q") from link 
(`http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=lai=CEvAD5thCTfHPCIq5gwe2lOWKD6n_uOIB4bzDkxm8uIhRCAAQASDrxZ0GKANQgI6s1ANgybblirSk2A-gAYem9NwDyAEBqQLN5n97JxulPqoEGk_QITE_eyPbZTKIyNFl8dQhptl05oxQ2fHjgAWQTg&sig=AGiWqtwLGY6f1Gnci0e0ojoRsLBxr9joLg&adurl=http://www.mediterraholidays.com/egypt/cairo-and-nile-cruise&rct=j&q=egpyt%20package%20trips`).

I used `^.*q=.*$` but with this. I need only after the j&q part if it has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use [`System.Uri`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) class for this:

```
Uri url = new Uri("http://www.google.com/aclk?sa=lai=CEvAD5thCTfHPCIq5gwe2lOWKD6n_uOIB4bzDkxm8uIhRCAAQASDrxZ0GKANQgI6s1ANgybblirSk2A-gAYem9NwDyAEBqQLN5n97JxulPqoEGk_QITE_eyPbZTKIyNFl8dQhptl05oxQ2fHjgAWQTg&sig=AGiWqtwLGY6f1Gnci0e0ojoRsLBxr9joLg&adurl=http://www.mediterraholidays.com/egypt/cairo-and-nile-cruise&rct=j&q=egpyt%20package%20trips");
var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Query);
var q = queryString["q"];
```

The `q` variable holds the value: `egpyt package trips`

Comment: I spend my 2 hours for this. U save my life :)

Answer (score 0):

```
&q=(?<data>[^&]*)
```

The answer needs to be at least 30 chars, so I add some joke:

> “Knock, knock.”
>
> “Who’s there?”
>
> very long pause….
>
> “Java.”

Comment: With this i can find link from link list if it has a q=  but i want only take a certain portion  (after the q= )

Comment: @s.esin: I'm sorry, I don't understand you. What you get is *egpyt%20package%20trips* in the `data` capturing group.